# How to translate along Z axis in OpenTK

Tags: opengl, c#, android, opentk

I am playing around with an OpenGL sample application I downloaded for Xamarin-Android. The sample application produces a rotating colored cube I would simply like to edit it so that the rotating cube is translated along the Z axis and disappears into the distance.

I modified the code by:

- adding an cumulative variable to store my Z distance,
- adding GL.Enable(All.DepthBufferBit) - unsure if I put it in the right place,
- adding GL.Translate(0.0f, 0.0f, Depth) - before the rotate functions,

Result: cube rotates a couple of times then disappears, it seems to be getting clipped out of the frustum.

So my question is what is the correct way to use and initialize the Z buffer and get the cube to travel along the Z axis? I am sure I am missing some function calls but am unsure of what they are and where to put them.

I apologise in advance as this is very basic stuff but am still learning :P, I would appreciate it if anyone could show me the best way to get the cube to still rotate but to also move along the Z axis. I have commented all my modifications in the code:

```
    // This gets called when the drawing surface is ready
    protected override void OnLoad (EventArgs e)
    {
        // this call is optional, and meant to raise delegates
        // in case any are registered
        base.OnLoad (e);

        // UpdateFrame and RenderFrame are called
        // by the render loop. This is takes effect
        // when we use 'Run ()', like below
        UpdateFrame += delegate (object sender, FrameEventArgs args) {
            // Rotate at a constant speed
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
                rot [i] += (float) (rateOfRotationPS [i] * args.Time);
        };

        RenderFrame += delegate {
            RenderCube ();
        };

        GL.Enable(All.DepthBufferBit);          //Added by Noob
        GL.Enable(All.CullFace);
        GL.ShadeModel(All.Smooth);

        GL.Hint(All.PerspectiveCorrectionHint, All.Nicest);

        // Run the render loop
        Run (30);
    }


    void RenderCube ()
    {
        GL.Viewport(0, 0, viewportWidth, viewportHeight);

        GL.MatrixMode (All.Projection);
        GL.LoadIdentity ();     

        if ( viewportWidth > viewportHeight )
        {
            GL.Ortho(-1.5f, 1.5f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        }
        else
        {
            GL.Ortho(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.5f, 1.5f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        }

        GL.MatrixMode (All.Modelview);
        GL.LoadIdentity ();
        Depth -= 0.02f;                          //Added by Noob
        GL.Translate(0.0f,0.0f,Depth);           //Added by Noob
        GL.Rotate (rot[0], 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        GL.Rotate (rot[1], 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        GL.Rotate (rot[2], 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        GL.ClearColor (0, 0, 0, 1.0f);
        GL.Clear (ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);

        GL.VertexPointer(3, All.Float, 0, cube);
        GL.EnableClientState (All.VertexArray);
        GL.ColorPointer (4, All.Float, 0, cubeColors);
        GL.EnableClientState (All.ColorArray);
        GL.DrawElements(All.Triangles, 36, All.UnsignedByte, triangles);

        SwapBuffers ();
    }
```

Comment: I have to imagine that `glEnable (GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)` generates a `GL_INVALID_ENUM`. The depth buffer is not something that can be enabled or disabled, you can enable or disable the ***depth test*** however or mask writes to the depth buffer **on** or **off**. Anything that ends in `Bit` in GL is used for commands that take bitmasks, such as `glClear (...)` or `glPushAttrib (...)` (in older versions of GL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to translate the cube AFTER you rotate it. The depth buffer has nothing to do with this.

If you first translate it, the vertices will be further away from origin, and then the rotation rotates them in relation to the origin, which results in a disappeared (out of view frustum) cube.

Also, while GL.Rotate and GL.Translate calls are supported, they are long deprecated feature. You should learn about using your own matrices with OpenTK's Matrix4 data structure. You can find great matrix tutorial from [here](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/). This probably will save you for some confusion about in which order the rotations and translations should be done.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help it works, it moves along the z axis while its rotating but its not quite what I had in mind. The cube now orbits around any selected axis in a growing trajectory. I would like it to spin in the same spot as it moves further away from the camera. should I translate the projection matrix ? I know they are deprecated, working my way up to matrices wanted to start with getting a basic example to work first. Am so grateful for your time.

Comment: That's why I swapped the order cause I want spinning in place effect but also for it to move slowly away from the camera and disappear into the distance along z axis.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get correct rotations, you need to translate your cube to the origin, rotate, then translate back to original location.  That way, you get a rotation that happens "in place" and not relative to some other location.....